# Change values of span using 1 function

Tags: javascript, counting

I'm trying to count the characters inside a texbox and put that number to a span using java script. How can I do it using 1 javascript function? They are all in a php variable.

```
$content="

<script language='JavaScript'>
   function here
</script>

<p><input type='text' name='title' onKeyUp='function()' />
    <br />character count: <span id='titlecharcount'>0</span></p>
<p><input type='text' name='description' onKeyUp='function()' />
    <br />character count: <span id='descriptioncharcount'>0</span></p>
";
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? In what way are you trying to change the "values"? (`span` elements don't have *values*; they do have content.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your `onKeyUp` attributes to pass in `this` and also the `id` of the span, e.g. (note the quotes):

```
<input type='text' name='title' onKeyUp="yourHandler(this, 'titlecharcount')" />
```

...then accept those arguments in your handler, the first will be a reference to the `input` element and the second will be a string giving the `id` of the span. You can then get the `span` element via `document.getElementById`. That lets you get and set its `innerHTML` property to get and set its contents. The value of an `input` is available as the `value` property of the input, so:

```
function yourHandler(input, id) {
    var span = document.getElementById(id);
    span.innerHTML = input.value.length;
}
```

---

Side note: I'd recommend using `onkeypress` rather than `onkeyup`. `onkeyup` only fires when the key is released, so your count won't get updated when someone holds down a key and gets key repeat.

Separately, write the attribute name in all lower case, not mixed case (`onkeypress` not `onKeyPress`).

Comment: how can I put this inside php variable like $content? I believe I cannot have it like this

$content="<input type='text' name='title' onKeyUp='yourHandler(this, 'titlecharcount')' />";

Comment: @KeithVarias: You'll have to use a double-quoted string or a heredoc string, [details in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). If you use a double-quoted string, you'll need to remove the literal line breaks (I believe), and to output a `"` you'll need to write `\"`. A heredoc string might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

span elements doesn't have value,they have inner content.you can change content using this function:

```
function changeLink(elementID)
{
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML="content";
}
```